# Can I make my Arduino a server using just GSM/GPRS Shield?

Tags: android, arduino, gsm, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I have seen examples of Arduino acting as a server using the Ethernet. But I am working on a project that requires my Arduino to act a server that will listen for client requests using no Ethernet, but only GSM/GPRS shield. I have a SIMCOM SIM808 GSM/GPRS/GPS module.

I will have my Android send requests to that Arduino & the Arduino will perform the operations accordingly. I have searched a lot, but haven't found any such example. That got me wondering if it was even possible? If yes, how?

Do feel free to direct me to links / posts that have such tutorial.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

of course it is possible.
GSM/GPRS shield will convert data to serial.
You will need to configure it with AT commands.

The main problem I see here is that GPRS will not have a fixed IP address, so you would not be able to reach it if you don't know the address.
Somehow the Arduino should send you every now and then its public IP address, which I am sure you can retrieve with an AT command.
Except also your mobile will not have a fixed IP address.
So you'll probably need a server in between to record IP addresses.

I am actually working on this type of problem, but use different hardware and libraries, so I am not able to help you more at the moment.
I will soon have a project on Kickstarter for this type of solution.